# How come this.hasOwnProperty('window') is true in chrome and false in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I run this code:

```
(function () {
    console.log(this,this.hasOwnProperty('window'))
})();
```

In chrome it outputs
[window] true

in IE11 it outputs
[window] false

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use window.hasOwnProperty() in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619666/is-there-a-way-to-use-window-hasownproperty-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE messes up the hasOwnProperty method completely as it’s painful with host Objects (host objects don’t have the hasOwnProperty method).

What we can do however is access the `Object.prototype` directly to guarantee any hasOwnProperty calls haven’t been tampered with or overridden.

```
var myObject= {
    prop: 'MyName',
    otherProp: null
};

if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObject, 'favouriteDrink')) { // true
    // do something if it exists
}
```

The secret here is `.call()` to change the context of hasOwnProperty (take that, IE) and ensure we have the exact hasOwnProperty we want from the Object.prototype.